# como multiplicar dos variables con decimales en bash?

Tags: linux, bash

eh tratado de realizar esta multiplicación pero me da error:

```
ganancia=$(($cap_inv*0,02))
```

y la he tratado como si fuera una división pero de igual me arroja error:

```
ganancia=$(echo "scale=2; $cap_inv*0,02 |bc)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### solución

```
ganancia=$(echo "scale=2;$cap_inv*0.02" | bc))
```

#### comprovación

```
➜  ~ cap_inv=1000
➜  ~ echo "scale=2;$cap_inv*0.02" | bc
20.00
➜  ~ ganancia=$(echo "scale=2;$cap_inv*0.02" | bc)
➜  ~ echo $ganancia
20.00
➜  ~
```

#### explicación

La calculadora BC no tiene en cuenta los locales del sistema, deben pasarse los números decimales con `punto` y no `comma`

Aún así:

```
ganancia=$(($cap_inv*0.02))
```

Tampoco funcionaria, ya que le estas diciendo que ejecute el comando del resultado de la expresión aritmética. Si la multiplicación da `30.200`, el valor de la variable ganancia serà la ejecucion de `30.200`, el cual no es ejecutable.